# angular 2 routerLink function Twice work

Tags: angular

In angular2 routerLink, I use [routerLink] = "[ 'XXXX', function() ]",but in partComponent the ***function twice work***

**app.component.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail/detail.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: DetailComponent},
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**detail.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail', nextInfo()]">
      下一个联系人
</a>
```

**detail.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ListComponent } from '../list/list.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  contact_id: string;
  private sub: any;
  numd = 1;
  constructor( private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router) {
    console.log('创建DeatilComponent组件实例');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.contact_id = params['id'];
      console.log('参数id为：' + this.contact_id);
    });
  }

  nextInfo() {
    console.log(this.numd);
    // this.numd++;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

why this ***nextInfo()*** twice work  in detail.component.ts.
I don't not why,as it a bug in angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** to this is use nextInfo() in `(click)` instead of using directly in `routerLink` :

Change :

```
// nextInfo will be invoked by itself on each time view refreshed
<a [routerLink]="['/detail', nextInfo()]"> 
      下一个联系人
</a>
```

To :

```
<a [routeLink]=['/detail', numd] (click)="nextInfo()">
      下一个联系人
</a>
```

> **Reason** is `changeDetection` cycle , in your case your function will
>   get called each time any changes made to the data and reflected to the
>   template side , To prevent that is should be fired on specific event ,
>   in your case its click.

For more detail read : **[LifeCycleHooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)**

This will help you to debug and also for understanding how flow goes.

Comment: Thanks,it's Ok .  If you tell me why  nextInfo()  twice work, that's so great

Comment: @zhiyuanbuqi , I have also specified the reason at the bottom as answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works twice is that you are in development mode. Change Detection triggers twice every time. Calling functions in your template is not a good practice because they are going to be called every time a change is detected.

If you enable prod mode and it will not trigger twice. However, I would still reconsider calling a function in the template.

Comment: Thanks，you're so great.

Comment: Cool, do you mind upvoting so that other people would see that this is a valid point?